Logback file is Empty
I am using spring 3.1.11 and below logback maven dependencies.
I tried lot of things but I am not getting any logs in my log file that is getting generated.
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

My loback-spring.xml file is as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <springProfile name="dev">
        <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>D:/logs/myprodapp.log</file>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>MyApp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
                <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <!-- Triggering policy - rollover daily -->
            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </appender>
        <logger name="com.anantaservice" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
        </logger>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
            <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>

I tried above configuration it is generating log file but it is empty.
I tried different versions of logback dependencies but still problem is the same.
